# Maven Builds on Jenkins

Tags: scala, maven, jenkins

On Jenkins, we have a build of a multi-module, scala based project.  The build configuration has three `Invoke top-level Maven targets` actions in the `Build` section:

```
// action 1: compiles the code
clean install -B -U -DskipTests=True
// action 2: run tests and generate coverage reports
scoverage:check site -Ptest.coverage.scala,test.coverage -B
// action 3: deploy code to nexus
deploy -B -DskipTests=true
```

Each action of the build appears to happen three times, and takes 21 minutes. Is it possible to combine the actions into a single action and decrease the build time?

Comment: If you do `mvn deploy` this includes `install`...why are you skipping the tests during `deploy` ...why not making `mvn clean deploy scoverage:check site ..`...? BTW: THe `-B` should already been set by Jenkins ...Do you have `SNAPSHOT` dependencies..? Furthermore `site` executes some parts of the build...so the result should be `mvn clean deploy scoverage:check site:site` ...I don't know your pom file so I can`t tell for sure....

Comment: yes, in this case there can be SNAPSHOT dependencies